# Use Database across the globe

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, scaling, globalization

I have a generic requirement just like any other big application, I want my user sitting in Asia to access my website hosted in the US region with the lowest latency(fastest speed), currently, it is not doing the same.

following is my infrastructure:

---

1. An app server: 4 core + 16 GB RAM, (max CPU usage is 15-20% in a
   day).
2. A DB server + 1 read replica : 4 core + 32 GB RAM (both) (max CPU    usage is 15-20% in a day). AWS Aurora DB with MYSQL

---

With this infrastructure, I am facing issues with latency(speed), My internet connection is quite good and stable.

To resolve this I have configured an app server in the Asia region and configured Geo-location routing to redirect users from Asia to this server, but the problem arises with DB, now I do not want to use a new DB, I want to use my existing DB, I a fine with creating replicas in Asia, but these replicas do not provide write capabilities, and connecting my Asia app server to US DB server is simply useless because of the latency and performance that I receive.

I have explored create another DB instance in the Asian region and start continuous replication, but the replication lag is unacceptable, due to the nature of the applicaiton.

I fine with changes in the architecture, but I wanted to know, how these big applications like Facebook, Zoom, Jira, even StackOverflow manage their users across the globe with little to NO latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are not design pattern for solving this, every ORG is suffering with the same issue and trying to solve this issue. Each global application has it's own highly customized architecture to tackle this issue.

There is some help from the cloud providers, but still the facilities they provide are not perfectly matched to the requirements here.
Hope we will get a solution to this in the future.